# Disappearing UIScrollView's indicator when rotating

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, rotation

I have two issues with scroll view.

(1)
When my scroll view is rotated, the scrollview's indicator is disappeared.
I call setFrame, setContentSize and setContentOffset when rotating.
There are lot of subviews on the scroll view, so content size is not small.
All my table views are good when rotating.

(2)
My app can restore user's reading position.
So I store the scroll view's contentOffset as CGPoint.
If I call setContentOffset to restore contentOffset, the scrollview's indicator is disappeared.
But when the view appear, if contentOffset values are set to (0.0, 0.0), the scrollview's indicator is not disappeared.
I tried to use scrollRectToVisible:animated:, the result is the same.

I spent over 10 hours today under these issues. Help me~ please.

// the part of creating

```
UIScrollView *scrollViewBoard = [ [ UIScrollView alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectZero ];
[ scrollViewBoard setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator: NO ];
[ scrollViewBoard setAlwaysBounceVertical: YES ];
[ scrollViewBoard setDelegate: self ];
[ self addSubview: scrollViewBoard ];
_board = scrollViewBoard;
[ scrollViewBoard release ];
```

// the part of rotating

```
- ( void ) adjustLayout: ( UIInterfaceOrientation )anOrientation {

MyTrackLog();
switch ( anOrientation ) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown: {
        [ _board setFrame: RECT_PORTRAIT_BOARD ];
    } break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight: {
        [ _board setFrame: RECT_LANDSCAPE_BOARD ];
    } break;
    default:
        break;
}
[ _board setContentSize: [ self calculateContentSize: anOrientation ] ];
[ _board setContentOffset: _contentOffset ];
[ self arrangeAchievementButtons: anOrientation ];
```

}   // adjustLayout:

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the `UIScrollView` extends the display.
 You could try:
The superview of the `UIScrollView` should set `autoResizeSubViews` to `YES`. And the `UIScrollView` should set `autoResizingMask` to `UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight`.
Don't use `setFrame` for resizing after an orientation change

Answer (score 0):

```
[_board flashScrollIndicators];
```

After you make the orientation change.